# Memory leakage while releasing Mat in opencv

Tags: opencv, memory-leaks, release, mat

I have a global variable `cv::Mat imageInputRGBA` which I want to release it at the end of my program in a clean up function. But I receive a memory leakage message like below from `Valgrind`. Could anyone please give me any advice how can I can free the the `Mat` memory correctly without memory leakage?:

```
==4499== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4499== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4499== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4499== Command: ./nwcc7 im2.png im6.png
==4499== 
==4499== 
==4499== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4499==     in use at exit: 6,086 bytes in 3 blocks
==4499==   total heap usage: 412 allocs, 409 frees, 25,693,438 bytes allocated
==4499== 
==4499== 30 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 3
==4499==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4499==    by 0x5D64679: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==4499==    by 0x698D59E: ??? (in /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.331.38)
==4499==    by 0x6578652F3938: ???
==4499== 
==4499== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 3
==4499==    at 0x4C2CC70: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4499==    by 0x60A268F: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:141)
==4499==    by 0x60A2197: dlsym (dlsym.c:70)
==4499==    by 0x698B8BD: ??? (in /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.331.38)
==4499==    by 0x6BCD5BF: ??? (in /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.331.38)
==4499==    by 0x6C00A5F: ???
==4499==    by 0x69B12CA: ??? (in /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.331.38)
==4499== 
==4499== 6,024 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==4499==    at 0x4C2CC70: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4499==    by 0x69A427E: ??? (in /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/libGL.so.331.38)
==4499== 
==4499== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4499==    definitely lost: 6,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==4499==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4499==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4499==    still reachable: 62 bytes in 2 blocks
==4499==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4499== 
==4499== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4499== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

//--------------------------------------
The code is something like this:

```
cv::Mat imageInputRGBA;
void CPU_cleanUp(){
  imageInputRGBA.release();
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  CPU_Part(argc,argv);// I didn't use imageInputRGBA in CPU_Part 
  CPU_cleanUp();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: a minimal code snippet might be helpful

Comment: ^^ no heap allocation at all there. (why do all the valgrind messages point to libGL.so ?)

Comment: @berak: I don't know. I have also a cuda file with .cu suffix in the project but I haven't call it any where and haven't used the imageInputRGBA variable in it.

Comment: again, where in the valgrind output do you see, that the cv::Mat is the culprit ? i'd rather look at cuda there. (besides that , no real idea)

Comment: when I put comment on cv::Mat imageInputRGBA the memory leakage disapears So I thought that cv::Mat imageInputRGBA would be the reson of memory leakage

Comment: Do you release the Mat manually? OpenCv uses garbage collection for cv::Mat so maybe its not even meant to release manually?!?

Comment: before declaring cv::Mat imageInputRGBA the program didn't have memory any leakage but after declaration of Cv::Mat ... either I release it or leave it for garbage collector (not using release function) it finds memory leakage